# Radeon HD 7700 causes monitor to go into power saving mode

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, amd-radeon

I have a LG Flatron M1717A monitor that has a VGA interface. When I bought a new computer with a HD 7700 card the monitor started going to power saving mode after the Windows loading screen. The solution was to turn off the monitor, turn it back on and quickly re-insert the plug (btw, I'm using a DVI-VGA adapter). Of course this was an annoying thing to do on every startup. So I figured out that plugging a HDMI TV once (later not needed) caused the problem to disappear...

Now I want to have a multi-monitor setup with LG being connected to the Radeon as a primary display and a second IBOX monitor to the motherboard's VGA connector.

This caused LG problems to reappear (only in multi-monitor setup, alone it works fine). So BIOS and Windows loading screen (rotating dots) use LG, then it switches to IBOX monitor on the login screen with LG going into suspend mode at the same time.

Now, re-plugging LG doesn't fix it. It does work either by sheer luck when re-plugging and/or messing with Catalyst. Plugging a HDMI TV causes Radeon to detect LG properly, but as soon as I disconnect HDMI, LG goes into suspend mode (unlike what I described earlier when it fixed things permanently).

It turned out that when I swap monitors (Radeon - IBOX, Integrated - LG) it works fine, but I can't set LG as a primary display and at the same time have Radeon render 3D graphics on it. Only when IBOX is primary I can have Radeon handle acceleration.

How do I fix this mess so that I can have a multi-monitor setup where LG is primary and play games on it with Radeon acceleration?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you are not plugging them both into the GPU at once? It sounds to me like your issues are being caused by plugging one monitor into the GPU and one into the motherboard which will use the integrated GPU. It may be possible to get around the issue doing something complicated but the by far simplest answer is just to plug them both into the dedicated GPU at once and use the AMD software to pick the primary.